# How to query from mongo db in react based on URL parameters

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I've a website say

http://localhost:3000/explore?location=Texas&bedroom=4

[This URL should query the mongo db database where location is Texas and bedroom is 4, all other fields have no filter]

http://localhost:3000/explore?location=Texas&bathroom=5
[This URL should query with fillets as location and bathroom, now the bedroom has no effect]

How to do such type of queries in mongo db and express js as back-end and react as front end

Please help me with the express js code and mongo db query

Thanks a lot in advanced

Comment: I've already developed the APIs of all the front end and back-end, only the searching part is left, I'm getting confused how to do that. Please let me how I handle the query parama in filter with conditions coming in express app

Answer (score 0):

**Back End**
First create your express app with mongoDB using the package Mongoose. You have to create a route who can get data from your db with parameter. Here a short exemple:

```
router.get('/search', function(req, res){
  YourCollection.findOne({/* Here the object with all the characteristics*/}, function(err, result)) {
    if(result == null) {
      res.status(400).send({
        message: "No Result"
      })
    } else {
      res.status(200).send({
        message: result
    }
  }
})
```

The route '/search' will seatch in the DB a result and send it back in json

**Front End**
Front end is easier you just have to create a fonction who can fetch an url who match with the route created earlier in the back ('/search'). Here a short exemple of the fonction that you can have in your react code:

```
        let requestConfig = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
            // Here all the characteristics that you have fetch in the url and these characteristics will be send to the back end in the req.body object
            })
        }

        fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/search", requestConfig).then((response) => this.setState({data: response})
```

Then you will have the result in your state or whatever. This is very complicate to explain it in a simple post. But there is a lot of tutorial on Google or Youtube to create an app like that. Good Luck !

Comment: I've already developed the APIs of all the front end and back-end, only the searching part is left, I'm getting confused how to do that. Please let me how I handle the query parama in filter with conditions coming in express app